# Can a callback function that belongs to a JavaScript object prototype access the object members?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, serverside-javascript

How can callback function that belong to a JavaScript object prototype access the object members?
the callback can't be closure, everything must be defined as follows:

```
function Obji(param){
   this.element = param;
}

Obji.prototype.func(){
   database.get("someKey",this.cb);
}

Obji.prototype.cb(){
   //here I would like to access this.element
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`database.get("someKey",this.cb.bind(this));`

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for older browsers

Answer (score 2):

In javascript `this` always points to the object on which the function is invoked or the global object if it's not invoked on anything. Can you do it this way?

```
Obji.prototype.func = function(){
   var ref = this;
   database.get("someKey", function(){ref.cb()});
}
```

Comment: You need a reference to the object. In javascript there's no link between a function and the object it's been assigned to. So unless you can smuggle a reference, f.i. via a closure, there's no way to do what you want. `this` never refers to the object the function is thought of as a member of, it always refers to the object the function is invoked on.

Comment: @entonio I wasn't sure if you are right or wrong, that's why I asked the question, it seems like you are wrong, check out @Raynos's answer

Comment: No, I'm not wrong. `bind` is a recently introduced function (i.e. not available in all browsers) that in this case merely does the same as the `function(){ref.cb()}` I proposed to you. What were the conditions that didn't allow you to use `function(){ref.cb()}` but allow `bind`?

Comment: (IOW, calling `bind` does create a closure.)

Comment: well, it's hard to explain, I am working on a program that rewrite other js programs and some things are much harder to parse than other things..my problem was that the function is already exists for the prototype object and I just need to pass an handler, .bind solved it

Comment: I take my words back, you were not wrong...anyhow @Raynos's solution is exactly what I was looking for..

Comment: Ok. Just bear in mind that `this.cb.bind(this)` is a new, different function form `this.cb`.

Comment: (Glad you got a lean solution. I just insisted on the point so that everybody remained aware of the nature of the object model.)

Comment: @entonio bind can be optimised more. Other then that it's the same. (apart from you can curry bind and set context to `null`)